# How to change CMake options from the Intellij platform plugin code?

Tags: clion, intellij-plugin

I want to change some options passed to the CMake command through the plugin code. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do it.

Is there any API to communicate with CLion specific functionality?

Comment: Since CLion is not opensource, I've spent hours to debug this to find the correct settings....

Comment: So, as I understand the only way to develop plugin for CLion is to dig into decompiled Java code of CLion? There are not any docs, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, there isn't. But if you're familiar with the IntelliJ Platform and master a JVM debugger, it's easier than you think (like, I just debugged it for hours, but if you're new to IntelliJ platform, you'll spend weeks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said "CMake command", which is unclear. I guess you want to change the CMake location.

This code can give you a `CPPToolchains.Toolchain` instance:

```
val Project.toolchains: CPPToolchains
    get() = ServiceManager
            .getService(this, CPPToolchains::class.java)
            .toolchains
            .firstOrNull()
```

Or if you don't understand Kotlin, use Java:

```
CPPToolchains.Toolchain tools = ServiceManager
        .getService(project, CPPToolchains.class)
        .getToolchains().get(0);
```

And you can get the settings by codes like

```
tools.getCMake().getExecutable()
```

Or change them by invoking methods like

```
com.jetbrains.cidr.cpp.toolchains.CPPToolchains.Toolchain#setCustomMakePath
```

Just explore through those classes and methods, you'll get what you want.

If you still can't find any, try replace `CPPToolchains` in the first two codes with `CMakeSettings` and see if there's something in the class that fits your expectation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! However, I'm looking for command line arguments passed to CMake executable, e.g. `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/some/path`. Do you know where in CLion project can I find it, at least approximately?

Comment: `CMakeSettings` maybe?

Comment: @KamilZaripov any plan of accepting my answer? I think I've provided all what you want. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake -> CMake Options

Comment: Yes I know how to find it in settings, but I want to do it programmatically inside plugin code.

Comment: Bad answer. You didn't understand the question at all.